# Is there a working version of Paint.mono for 11.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, 11.04, image-editor

I'm looking for an Ubuntu 11.04 version of paint.mono
Is there a package available for download?
I found [this on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/paintnet-for-linux-paintmono.html) but it only shows previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard about paint.mono, but I suppose it's a clone of Microsoft's Paint.Net application.

There is a graphics editor called [Pinta](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pinta), and it's inspired by Paint.Net. Moreover, it's written in C# and uses Mono library. It is in Ubuntu repositories.

Update: [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET):

> As of December 2010, paint-mono is no longer maintained and hasn't
> been updated since March 2009. There is also a project called Pinta
> which is described as a clone of Paint.NET for Mono and GTK